# Requisição jquery dando erro

Tags: php, jquery

pessoal eu estou com o seguinte problema eu tenho uma pagina onde coloca os comentários tudo certinho ai carrega até 5 comentários até aqui tudo funciona o que ocorre é que nesses 5 comentários tem um botão que você clica e aparece em fadeIn o campo para por resposta até aqui tudo certo, mas quando clico em mostrar mais comentários ele pucha de outra pagina e esses que vem quando é clico em responder não funciona não sei por que.

código fonte:

javascript

```
$('.resposta').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).children('input').val();
        alert(id);
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).parents('.coment').find('.resp').fadeIn("slow");

        $('form[name="responder"]').submit(function(){
           return false; 
        });

        return false;
    });
```

página php onde já exibe os 5 comentários

```
<?php 
                       /*
                     **********************************************
                     **********************************************
                     ***********Função para exibição dos***********
                     ****************comentarios*******************
                     **********************************************/

                        $comentar = new Read;
                  $comentar ->ExeRead('coment', 'WHERE video = :video ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5', "video={$sei[1]}");
                  foreach ($comentar->getResult() as $big):
                      extract($big);
                  $image = new Read;
                  $image ->ExeRead('users', 'WHERE id = :id', "id={$big['user']}");
                  foreach ($image->getResult() as $imx)
                      extract ($imx);
                /*
                     **********************************************
                     **********************************************
                     *********Fim da função de exibição************
                     ***************de comentarios*****************
                     **********************************************/
                  echo "<input type='text' hidden='hidden' value='{$link}' id='link'>";
                  ?>
                    <div class='comentar  fl-left'>
                        <div class='coment com' >

                                <?php 

                    if($foto == "" || $foto == "uploads/"):
                        echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='".REQUIRE_PATH."/css/boot/icons/thumb.png'></a>";
                    else:
                        echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='{$imx['foto']}'></a>";
                    endif;
                    ?>
                   <p><small class='fontze1'>Comentado por:</small> <?=$nome?> <small>Em:  </small> <?=$date?> <small>As: </small> <?=$hora?></p>

                   <div class="comentando">
                       <p><?=nl2br($comentario)?></p></div>
                       <div class='fl-right resposta'>Responder<input type='hidden' value='<?=$big[id] ?>' name='idcoment'>
                       </div>
                       <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
                           <form method='post'><textarea></textarea>  

                               <input class='btn btn-green' type='submit' value='responder' name='responder'>
                           </form>
                       </div>
                   </div>


                        <?php
                    endforeach;    

                    endforeach;

                    endforeach; 
                    ?>
                    <center><div id='load' class='btn btn-blue btn-full'>Mostar mais comentários</div></center> <div class='clear'></div>
                  </div>
```

pagina onde é puchado o mostrar mais

```
<?php
include '../_app/Config.inc.php';

// Função do jquery para listar os comentários
if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'acao') ==  'comentarios'){

    $video = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'video');
    $numcom = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'numcom');

    $readCount = new Read ();
    $readCount ->ExeRead('coment', "WHERE video = :video LIMIT $numcom,4", "video={$video}");

    echo $readCount->getRowCount();

}

// Função do jquery para exibir mais comentários

if(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'acao') ==  'morecoment'){
    $video = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'video');
    $numcom = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'numcom');

    $readCount = new Read ();

    $readCount ->FullRead("SELECT * FROM coment WHERE video = :video ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $numcom,3", "video={$video}" );


        foreach ($readCount->getResult() as $cat):
        extract($cat);
        $image = new Read;
                  $image ->ExeRead('users', 'WHERE id = :id', "id={$cat['user']}");

                  foreach ($image->getResult() as $imx):
                      extract ($imx);
                  echo "<div class='coment com' style='display:none'>";
                    if($foto == "" || $foto == "uploads/"):
                        echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='".REQUIRE_PATH."/css/boot/icons/thumb.png'></a>";
                    else:
                        echo  "<a href='user?id={$id}'><img class='fl-left' src='{$imx['foto']}'></a>";
                    endif;
                       ?>
                       <p><small class='fontze1'>Comentado por:</small> <?=$nome?> <small>Em:  </small> <?=$date?> <small>As: </small> <?=$hora?></p>

                                <div class="comentando">
                       <p><?=nl2br($comentario)?></p></div>
                       <div class='fl-right resposta'>Responder<input type='hidden' value='<?=$big[id] ?>' name='idcoment'>
                       </div>
                       <div class=' resp' style='display:none'>
                           <form name='responder' method='post'><textarea></textarea>  

                               <input class='btn btn-green' type='button' value='responder' name='responder'>
                           </form>
                       </div></div>

                        <?php


                   endforeach;           
               endforeach;           
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você executa o jQuery lá no início, ele encontra todas as divs com classe "resposta" e aplica os eventos que você programou na função de resposta, certo?

Só que quando você carrega mais comentários, ele não faz isso de novo, por que ele já fez uma vez (nos primeiros 5 comentários que já estavam na página).

Ou seja: você precisa executar esse script nas novas respostas.

**Mas tem um problema**

Se você executar esse mesmo seletor, ele vai colocar dois eventos nos primeiros cinco comentários, por que o jQuery usa o `setEventListener` para registrar o evento de clique. Ou seja, ele vai executar duas vezes e ocupar mais memória à toa, além de que pode dar dor de cabeça mais tarde. Para resolver isso, cria uma função que faça duas coisas: retire os eventos todos dos objetos e depois coloque de novo.

```
function addEventosRespostas() {
   $('.resposta')
       .off("click")
       .on("click", function(){
         ...
       });
}
```

**Outra coisa**
Evite usar `.click()` por que ele está pra sair do jQuery mais atual (deve ter saído já, tem tempo que ouço isso). O padrão hoje em dia é `.on()`

**Referências**

http://api.jquery.com/off/

http://api.jquery.com/on/